# Command not found roscd, rosnode, etc

Tags: ros, rosnode, roscd, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow this tutorial to get ROS in my mac:
http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/MacPorts/Repository
I followed it and seems that everything is working perfect, but when I try roscd or rosnode it says command not found. Does anybody know how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195052/command-not-found-roscd,-rosnode,-etc./) by [FelipC](https://answers.ros.org/users/20477/felipc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-10-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@FelipC can you verify that you have rosbash in your workspace which you installed? This package provides the bash functions which you seem to be missing. You can look for it in the src/ros_comm folder.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source the `setup.bash` in the resulting `install_isolated` folder?

You have to make sure to source the `setup.bash` rather than the `setup.sh` otherwise you will not get command line tools which are actually bash functions, like `roscd`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-10-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FelipC](https://answers.ros.org/users/20477/felipc/) on 2014-10-15**:
Yes, I did this:
source /opt/local/setup.bash
And other commands are working like roscore...

**Comment by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on 2014-10-15**:
Did you also add it to your .bashrc file?
In my case it is: source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash (but your's may be right for you)
You find the .bashrc in your "personal folder" (i have the german version). There you press CTRL+H.
This change will source the setup.bash after every restart.

**Comment by [FelipC](https://answers.ros.org/users/20477/felipc/) on 2014-10-15**:
I did it right now but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing ros--rosbash package! This should resolve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [Sandeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/25496/sandeep/) with karma: 31 on 2016-01-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spri](https://answers.ros.org/users/28266/spri/) on 2016-10-16**:
it worked,thanks a lot

**Comment by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on 2017-09-06**:
This worked for me. (ros-indigo)